# TLS, headers and proxies : how to answer the client?

Tags: ssl, encryption, nginx, reverse-proxy

## CONTEXT :

I try to familiarize myself with web technology.
I've been learning sockets recently and now raise the bar to tcp servers.

I have two servers : one frontend and one database server.
Frontend : nginx
DB server : custom tcp server for database connection.

TLS encryption activated.

Nginx - Debian 64.

## PROBLEM :

Frontend is named A and Database is named B.

I would like to understand how I can have A as a ssl termination point, pass the request to B server and finally send back the query to A so that is answers the client with TLS.

From what I understand :

1) client requests server for ssl handshake

2) server accepts and does that according to the cert it is related with

3) client make a query

4) server look at the payload and knows that it is good because it may have a cache somewhere

5) but the query has to be proxied on LAN so the server proxies the request in clear

6) the other server treats the query and answer back to the frontend

7) frontend encrypts again the whole response and sends it again to the client.

How 7) happens ? I think that it cannot be reencrypted randomly, right ? it has to get a key in a cache or something, no ?

What I need is confirmation or explanation  on this point 7).

Comment: What's the issue with headers specifically? The DB server returns a response and the other thing sends it to the client via SSL. Headers aren't specially treated. It's all payload.

Comment: I don't understand the payload thing. I just cannot figure out how a server is able to recover the ssl session.

Comment: I can't understand anything about the question at all. Try again.

Comment: I re-phrased my question as asked

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by 'how can a webserver know which ssl payload it has to choose from the many it has.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How 7) happens ? I think that it cannot be reencrypted randomly, right ? it has to get a key in a cache or something, no ?

7 happens by encrypting the response data with the session key that was negotiated during the SSL handshake.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a header that keeps that information ?

Comment: The session key is never transmitted at all. What use exactly would an encrypted message be that contained its own decryption key? And why are you so fixated on headers?

Comment: Because I try to understand how it works :). Since there is a session it has to be passed somewhere so that the server could say yes it client A or client B... You cannot use a random session every time, could you ?

Comment: Of course not. The session key is computed independently by both ends using a secure key agreement protocol. If it was transmitted with the message anybody could use it to decrypt the message so it would be completely pointless and utterly insecure. You seem to be really asking how SSL works, which is far too broad to cover here. There are excellent books on it, and the RFCs (2246 and following).